# how to trigger a AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

what application would be able to trigger the audio focus (on a physical device):     AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK?

Already tried sending and email to the device and no sound was recieved nor was the onAudioFocusChange() triggered

Answer (score 2):

Facebook messages will trigger this AudioFocus

Comment: Thanks! Actually any push notificatio sound will trigger this, i.e. email, whatsapp etc.

Answer (score 0):

As of October 2015, there is a "Play test sound" in Google Maps settings:

1. Open Google Maps
2. Open Settings
3. Select "Navigation Settings"
4. Press "Play test sound"

Comment: It triggers AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT for me